# How to generate rows for missing homeworks?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Suppose I have a table of students, the dates they completed their homework, and how they performed. For example: t1

```
Name     Date        Result 
Carlos   2019-06-01  Average 
Carlos   2019-06-02  Outstanding 
Carlos   2019-06-03  Outstanding 
Ernesto  2019-06-01  Average 
Ernesto  2019-06-02  Average 
Ernesto  2019-06-03  Failed 
Miguel   2019-06-02  Average 
Miguel   2019-06-03  Average
Ashley   2019-06-01  Outstanding 
Ashley   2019-06-02  Outstanding
Eddie    2019-06-01  Failed 
Eddie    2019-06-03  Failed
```

As you can see from the table, there are no records for Miguel(2019-06-01), Ashley(2019-06-03), and Eddie(2019-06-02). In those scenarios, I would like to generate an extra row whenever there's a missing homework.

I would like to generate a new table like this:

```
Name     Date        Result 
Carlos   2019-06-01  Average 
Carlos   2019-06-02  Outstanding 
Carlos   2019-06-03  Outstanding 
Ernesto  2019-06-01  Average 
Ernesto  2019-06-02  Average 
Ernesto  2019-06-03  Failed
Miguel   2019-06-01  Missing      --New row
Miguel   2019-06-02  Average 
Miguel   2019-06-03  Average
Ashley   2019-06-01  Outstanding 
Ashley   2019-06-02  Outstanding
Ashley   2019-06-03  Missing      --New row
Eddie    2019-06-01  Failed
Eddie    2019-06-02  Missing      --New row
Eddie    2019-06-03  Failed
```

Any clues?

Thanks guys!

Comment: There are a lot of topics and posts about gaps and islands.

Comment: See [It appears no attempt was made](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) and [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Comment: Join it to a [calendar table](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4054/creating-a-date-dimension-or-calendar-table-in-sql-server/)

Comment: By "I would like to generate an extra row", do you want to add the row to the table or just during your select statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `cross join` to generate the rows and a `left join` to bring in the values:

```
select n.name, d.date, coalesce(t1.result, 'Missing') as result
from (select distinct name from t1) n cross join
     (select distinct date from t1) d left join
     t1
     on t1.name = n.name and t1.date = d.date;
```

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately in my case, the d table part didn't work for scenarios where, for example, if there were homeworks on the 2019-06-04, then the table wouldn't populate anything for those dates, which is kind of my fault, since I didn't specify all the conditions. I ended up using this instead "SELECT  TOP (DATEDIFF(DAY, DATEADD(day,-30,getdate()),getdate()) + 1)
        Date = convert(date,DATEADD(DAY, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY a.object_id) - 1, DATEADD(day,-30,getdate())))
FROM    sys.all_objects a
        CROSS JOIN sys.all_objects b"

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `left join` the result table based  on cross join between `name` and `date`

```
select t3.name, t3.date, m.result 
from  (
  select  t2.name, t1.date
  from (
    select distinct date  
    from my_table  
  ) t1
  cross join (
   select distinct name  
   from my_table 
  ) t2 
) t3 
left join  my_table m  on m.name = t3.name and m.date = t3.date
```

Answer (score -1):

In case you want the new generated to be added directly to the table you can do the following.

```
declare @MinDate        date,
        @MaxDate        date,
        @Name           varchar(30)

declare cur_std cursor for select distinct name from t1
open cur_std
fetch next from cur_std into @Name
while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
begin
select @MinDate = Min(Date), @MaxDate = Max(Date) from t1
    while @MinDate <= @MaxDate
    begin
        if not exists (select * from t1 where Name = @Name and Date = @MinDate)
        begin
            insert into t1 values(@Name, @MinDate, 'Missing')
        end
        set @MinDate = DATEADD(dd,1,@MinDate)
    end

    fetch next from cur_std into @Name
end
close cur_std
deallocate cur_std

select * from t1
```